# Generate a JAR file that links the assets for a LibGDX project using gradle

Tags: java, netbeans, gradle, jar, libgdx

i'm having an issue when i try to generate a jar file for a desktop game that i made using LibGDX. The problem is that i run the following command:

```
gradlew desktop:dist
```

in the Windows command line it generates the jar file in Project/desktop/build/libs folder but when i double click it it closes immediately.

I tried to run it with the following command:

```
java -jar desktop-1.0.jar
```

It prints this
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPX3L.png)

I'm new to LibGDX and graddle but i think the problem is in the gradle.build file in my desktop project folder, in the line

```
project.ext.assetsDir = new File("../core/assets");
```

My assets are in the core project folder since i unchecked the Android box in the LibGDX project setup and it runs properly when i do it in Netbeans (using the gradle project plug in).

I'm desperate, this is the last thing that i need to finish this project at the uni.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the mistake, i opened the jar file with 7zip and saw that the images folder changed its name, so i changed it again and it worked.

Hope this helps someone in the future.